# Is there a single word for a decision that hasn't been made yet?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a single word (a noun) that indicates a decision that has not been made versus a decision that has been made... a single word for "pending decision" vs. "concluded decision".

To better understand why I'm asking, please consider the following verbs:

1. "We need to make a decision" vs "We made a decision"
2. "We need to decide" vs "We decided"

I'm looking for a single word replacement for *decison-to-be-made* in the following:
"This is the *decision-to-be-made*"

Many dictionaries define the noun **decision** as both a conclusion that has been reached and as a process for deciding. For me it's always troubling when a form of the word is used in the definition of the word.

Comment: how about "pending"

Comment: The decided decision is a "conclusion".

Comment: Please provide a sample sentence where the word decision needs replacing by another. You may find the ambiguity of certain words in the English language unsatisfactory, but the rest of us get by all right. It seems worse in other languages — the Germans don't generally distinguish between rabbits and hares — but it's just psychology.

Comment: Your example seems to be looking for a *verb* (to replace *need to decide*). I had been going to suggest *"We **pondered**. vs "We decided."* However, you earlier say that you are looking for a *noun*. Which is it?

Comment: Thanks Jason and David - really looking for a noun.
I'm wanting to replace _decision-to-be-made_ with a single word:
"This is the _decision-to-be-made_" vs "This is the decision".

Comment: This is about to turn into the weirdest comment that I have left in quite some time, but I would like to humbly submit that Germans do generally distinguish between rabbits and hares. And it's not just psychology, it's actually two completely different words that mean two completely different things. Ein Hase ist kein Kaninchen, und das weiß jedes Kind. It seems worse in English — they don't generally distinguish between turtles and tortoises — and it's not just psychology, [even experts in casual conversation get them mixed up](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/10268/300).

Comment: Before the decision is made, it is a *proposal*.

Comment: I agree with Lawrence.  Note, in UK English, I believe you can use *table* as a synonym for *propose (verb)*: "This is what has been tabled."  Careful, *table* has a different meaning in US English.  But in US English, you can say, "This is what's on the table."  Also: "This is what's under consideration," "This is what's pending," "This is what's pending."

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Lawrence. Proposal is certainly close, but often times a group has to decide between many proposals. "We need to decide which _proposal_ to pick"

Comment: How about: "That proposal is _still undecided_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, there isn't a single word for a decision that has not been made yet.

The two word phrase "Pending decision" conveys the meaning of "decision that hasn't been made".

The two word phrase "Concluded decision" conveys the meaning of "decision that has been made.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use **idea** (or one of its [synonyms](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english-thesaurus/idea#idea__1)).

> An idea is a plan, suggestion, or possible course of action.
>   <sub>[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/idea)</sub>

For example, here it is used in contrast to *decision*:

- [Idea > Decision > Action](http://www.cluttercoach.net/2016/03/idea-decision-action/)
- [How to Start: 30 Days from Idea to Decision](https://generalassemb.ly/education/how-to-start-30-days-from-idea-to-decision)